# List element type from csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a simple csv file which I would like to use to create a function to evaluate only the integer values. Below is the code:

```
def type_setter(x):                                                                                                                           
    x = list(x)                                                                                                                               
    for i in x:                                                                                                                               
        for j in i :                                                                                                                          
            print type(j)                                                                                                                     
            if isinstance(j,int)==True:                                                                                                       
                eval(j)                                                                                                                   

    return x
```

The problem is that the `j` values are all seen as string variables, not a mix of integers and strings. Any ideas why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fields are strings. You can't use `isinstance(j, int)` because it will always return `False`.

Use [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) instead:

```
>>> '1234'.isdigit()
True
>>> 'abcd'.isdigit()
False
>>> '-1234'.isdigit()
False
>>> '-1234'.lstrip('-').isdigit()
True
```

Or create a helper function that use try-except with [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
def is_int(x):
    try:
        int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Example:

```
>>> is_int('1234')
True
>>> is_int('xyz')
False
>>> is_int('-1')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python one should lean towards *better to ask forgiveness than permission* rather than towards *look before you leap*.

In other words, you should proceed as though you could convert the incoming token to integer and process it, rather than first checking if you can (e.g. *looking before you leap*). If you cannot make the conversion, a `ValueError` will be thrown, which you can catch and dismiss (the *ask for forgiveness* part).

```
for token in tokens:
 try:
   process(int(token))
 except ValueError:
   continue
```

The Python documentation has the following to say about [*duck typing*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-duck-typing):

> **duck-typing**
>
> A programming style which does not look at an object’s type to
>   determine if it has the right interface; instead, the method or
>   attribute is simply called or used (“If it looks like a duck and
>   quacks like a duck, it must be a duck.”) By emphasizing interfaces
>   rather than specific types, well-designed code improves its
>   flexibility by allowing polymorphic substitution. Duck-typing avoids
>   tests using type() or isinstance(). (Note, however, that duck-typing
>   can be complemented with abstract base classes.) Instead, it typically
>   employs hasattr() tests or EAFP programming.

Where EAFP programming is defined as:

> **EAFP**
>
> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many try and except
>   statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many
>   other languages such as C.